# Response 400 <Bad request> on a dreamfactory API POST call

Tags: python, mongodb, import, dreamfactory

I am trying to post a request from my Python application to a MongoDB running on my localhost using dreamfactory API. However, I get a 400 response back. There are no issues with the connectivity to MongoDb as the post request works fine from Dreamfactory stack manager. Code I am using is as below. Any idea what is it I am doing wrong.

```
    import requests
    import json
    import yaml
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import date, datetime
    url="http://127.0.0.1:27017/api/v2/db/_table/test" 

    def remove_dots(obj):
        for key in obj.keys():
            new_key = key.replace(".","-")
            if new_key != key:
                obj[new_key] = obj[key]
                del obj[key]
        return obj

    json_obj_dict={'Name': 'Zara', 'Age.Key': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
    new_json = json.dumps(json_obj_dict)
    json_final=json.loads(new_json, object_hook=remove_dots)
    json_final={"resource":[json_final]}
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-DreamFactory-API-Key":"36fda24fe5588fa4285ac6c6c2fdfbdb6b6bc9834649774c9bf777f706d05a88" }
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=json.dumps(json_final))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the role associated with the API key you are passing have the correct privileges?  In other words, if you do not have a default role assigned, you most likely are getting the 400 because you are not passing in a session token (JWT) in your header along with the API key.  You are allowed to pass the API Key with the JWT if you have assigned a default role that allows the requested verb(GET, POST, etc.) call.

http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Troubleshooting#Common_Errors
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Setting_up_application_default_role
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Features/Auth#Authentication